# sudoers rule to start and stop eth interface

Tags: sudoedit

I got syntax error when i add this rules to sudoers :

```
ifdown eth0:1
ifup eth0:1
```

I also try with :

```
ifdown eth0\:1
ifup eth0\:1
```

And:

```
ifdown "eth0:1"
ifup "eth0:1"
```

How to allow a non root user to start and stop the `eth0:1` interface  ?

Comment: Why you are adding the network command to your sudoers files?

Comment: username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/ifdown eth0\:1,/sbin/ifup eth0\:1

Comment: @GAD3R i add them to give a non root user the ability the start and stop the interface eth0:1

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` with `visudo -f /etc/suoders.d/mysudo` and replace username with your username 
`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/ifdown eth0\:1,/sbin/ifup eth0\:1`